# Corda-specific web server is deprecated and will be removed in future

Tags: corda

The nodes running on our mac os show `error` info as below. This has occurred on two separate machines.

```
Last login: Wed Oct 31 12:48:00 on ttys004
bash -c 'cd "/Users/chrisceliberti/PropertyListing/PropertyListing/PropertyListing/PropertyListing/PropertyListing/PropertyListing/build/nodes/PartyB" ; "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java" "-Dname=PartyB-corda-webserver.jar" "-Dcapsule.jvm.args=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5009 -javaagent:drivers/jolokia-jvm-1.3.7-agent.jar=port=7009,logHandlerClass=net.corda.webserver.JolokiaSlf4Adapter" "-jar" "corda-webserver.jar" && exit'
chriss-Air-2:~ chrisceliberti$ bash -c 'cd "/Users/chrisceliberti/PropertyListing/PropertyListing/PropertyListing/PropertyListing/PropertyListing/PropertyListing/build/nodes/PartyB" ; "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java" "-Dname=PartyB-corda-webserver.jar" "-Dcapsule.jvm.args=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5009 -javaagent:drivers/jolokia-jvm-1.3.7-agent.jar=port=7009,logHandlerClass=net.corda.webserver.JolokiaSlf4Adapter" "-jar" "corda-webserver.jar" && exit'
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5009
This Corda-specific web server is deprecated and will be removed in future.
Please switch to a regular web framework like Spring, J2EE or Play Framework.
```

Should I utilize another web server like `Spring` or is there another fix?

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to another webserver like Spring.

Although Corda 3 includes a node webserver, this is a deprecated feature that continues to exist only for demo purposes. You should create your own production-grade webserver using existing technologies.

See the Spring Webserver sample [here](https://github.com/corda/spring-webserver). This is a Spring webserver that connects to a Corda node. How does this example work?

1. We create a `Component` that is initialised when the server starts and establishes a long-lasting RPC connection to the node:

   ```
   /**
   * Wraps a node RPC proxy.
   *
   * The RPC proxy is configured based on the properties in `application.properties`.
   *
   * @param host The host of the node we are connecting to.
   * @param rpcPort The RPC port of the node we are connecting to.
   * @param username The username for logging into the RPC client.
   * @param password The password for logging into the RPC client.
   * @property proxy The RPC proxy.
   */
   @Component
   open class NodeRPCConnection(
       @Value("\${$CORDA_NODE_HOST}") private val host: String,
       @Value("\${$CORDA_USER_NAME}") private val username: String,
       @Value("\${$CORDA_USER_PASSWORD}") private val password: String,
       @Value("\${$CORDA_RPC_PORT}") private val rpcPort: Int): AutoCloseable {

       lateinit var rpcConnection: CordaRPCConnection
           private set
       lateinit var proxy: CordaRPCOps
           private set

       @PostConstruct
       fun initialiseNodeRPCConnection() {
           val rpcAddress = NetworkHostAndPort(host, rpcPort)
           val rpcClient = CordaRPCClient(rpcAddress)
           val rpcConnection = rpcClient.start(username, password)
           proxy = rpcConnection.proxy
       }

       @PreDestroy
       override fun close() {
           rpcConnection.notifyServerAndClose()
       }
   }
   ```
2. We inject this `Component` into each controller, and use it to interact with the node:

   ```
   /**
    * A CorDapp-agnostic controller that exposes standard endpoints.
    */
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/") // The paths for GET and POST requests are relative to this base path.
   class StandardController(private val rpc: NodeRPCConnection) {

       companion object {
           private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestController::class.java)
       }

       private val proxy = rpc.proxy

       @GetMapping(value = "/status", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
       private fun status() = "200"

       @GetMapping(value = "/servertime", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
       private fun serverTime() = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(proxy.currentNodeTime(), ZoneId.of("UTC")).toString()

       @GetMapping(value = "/addresses", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
       private fun addresses() = proxy.nodeInfo().addresses.toString()

       @GetMapping(value = "/identities", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
       private fun identities() = proxy.nodeInfo().legalIdentities.toString()

       @GetMapping(value = "/platformversion", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
       private fun platformVersion() = proxy.nodeInfo().platformVersion.toString()

       @GetMapping(value = "/peers", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
       private fun peers() = proxy.networkMapSnapshot().flatMap { it.legalIdentities }.toString()

       @GetMapping(value = "/notaries", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
       private fun notaries() = proxy.notaryIdentities().toString()

       @GetMapping(value = "/flows", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
       private fun flows() = proxy.registeredFlows().toString()

       @GetMapping(value = "/states", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
       private fun states() = proxy.vaultQueryBy<ContractState>().states.toString()
   }
   ```

Comment: Joel thanks. I'm new to this so this so do I just clone the Spring Server Zip and utilize the server folder adding it as a module within Intelli J? If not please suggest the best way to implement this

Comment: You can just have it as a standalone project. It doesn't need to be in the same project as a module.

Comment: Thanks Joel. When I looked at the pre-requisites it says to download cordapp-example. Do I need to utilize this in intelliJ first or do I just go ti intelliJ and add it as a stand-alone project? Thanks again for your help

Comment: I've actually just rewritten the templates to use Spring as a webserver - it may be easier to look there. See https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin and https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java.

Comment: @Joel templates are not working with corda 4.0. Can you please answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54866720/7809145