# Corda ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException while running server

Tags: java, spring, gradle, corda, activemq-artemis

I am trying to run Corda application after modifying the given template.
After running nodes, I am trying to run a template server. Below are the details for

- Corda Version: 4.0
- ActiveMQ running on port 8161

```
task runTemplateServer(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.template.webserver.ServerKt'
    args '--server.port=10050', '--config.rpc.host=localhost', '--config.rpc.port=8161', '--config.rpc.username=admin', '--config.rpc.password=admin'
}
```

After running above task, I am getting following exception.
I saw the notes and upgraded Corda to v4.0 but still I'm not able to run the server.

```
E 17:15:13 1 SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller' defined in file [template/webserver/Controller.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nodeRPCConnection': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1274) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.template.webserver.ServerKt.main(Server.kt:23) [main/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nodeRPCConnection': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException: AMQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:814) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:216) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:93) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:32) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:193) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:183) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:72) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:392) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:375) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:344) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.template.webserver.NodeRPCConnection.initialiseNodeRPCConnection(NodeRPCConnection.kt:44) ~[main/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 17 more

> Task :clients:runTemplateServer FAILED
```

What I have tried:

1. Upgrading corda to v4.0 as specified in one github issue
2. Adding jolokia as jvm agent

Nothing is working. can anyone please help?

Comment: please provide your node.conf, JVM and gradle version. also your node logs

Comment: @Kid101 I am just running the template Corda has provided. Regarding gradle, the distribution url is https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip

Comment: cannot find any `runTemplateServer` in `https://github.com/corda/samples/`

Comment: @Kid101 I am using https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin as provided on official website.

Comment: I could make it work, are you sure that your nodes are running? which JVM ?

Comment: @Kid101 It is Java 1.8. https://ibb.co/m8d2dFG.

Comment: @Kid101 I think there may be a mistake from my side. Let me check.

Comment: @Kid101 Thanks for drawing my attention. I was following the README blindly and forgot to deploy and run nodes. Can you please put the answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nodes have to be started first before the client should be able to connect to it.

1. do a `gradlew clean deployNodes` to create the nodes.
2. run the nodes `build\nodes\runnodes`
3. Once the nodes have started, start the client `gradlew runTemplateServer`

This way the client would be able to connect to the Node. 
As can be seen from logs. `nodeRPCConnection` `init` failed because it wasn't able to connect to the node.

Comment: I have the same issue with the 4.8 enterprise version. I have tried this but it was not successful.  What can be the reason? And I am working with the sample project

Answer (score 0):

For me such command was successful

```
val processWeb = ProcessBuilder(listOf("java", "-jar",
                (nodePath / "corda-spring-webserver.jar").toString(),
                "--server.port=$serverPort", "--config.rpc.username=username", "--config.rpc.password=password",
                "--config.rpc.host=host", "--config.rpc.port=port"))
                .directory((nodePath).toFile())
                .redirectErrorStream(true)
                .redirectOutput((nodePath / "logs" / "web-server-info-run.log").toFile())
                .apply { environment()["CAPSULE_CACHE_DIR"] = "../.cache" }
                .start()
```